# C++ new[] operator creates array of length = length + 1?

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

Why does the new[] operator in C++ actually create an array of length + 1? For example, see this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    int length;
    std::cin >> length;

    int *array = new int[length]; // use array new.  Note that length does not need to be constant!
    //int *array;

    std::cout << "I just allocated an array of integers of length " << length << '\n';

    for (int n = 0; n<=length+1; n++)
    {
      array[n] = 1; // set element n to value 1
    }

    std::cout << "array[0] " << array[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << "array[length-1] " << array[length-1] << '\n';
    std::cout << "array[length] " << array[length] << '\n';
    std::cout << "array[length+1] " << array[length+1] << '\n';

    delete[] array; // use array delete to deallocate array
    array = 0; // use nullptr instead of 0 in C++11

    return 0;
}
```

We dynamically create an array of length "length" but we are able to assign a value at the index length+1. If we try to do length+2, we get an error.

Why is this? Why does C++ make the length = length + 1?

Comment: ***We dynamically create an array of length "length" but we are able to assign a value at the index length+1. If we try to do length+2, we get an error*** Undefined Behavior. When you step outside the allocated bounds anything can happen.

Comment: no, c++ did not change the length. c++ only allow you to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Dynamic memory blocks have overhead. When you call free () or delete, it needs to know how big the block was so as to free the correct amount. Usually, there is a link at the beginning and end to allow for easy merging back into the memory pool (part of the same block at the OS level) and it's probably this that you are overwriting.

Comment: What disadvantage is there to stepping outside the allocated bounds?

Comment: You are writing to memory that is, or can be, used by something else.

Comment: I see. I was just confused why it is allowed and didn't cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: ***I was just confused why it is allowed and didn't cause a segmentation fault.*** It does not have to crash. c++ does not do anything at all to prevent you from doing this.

Comment: Segment faults are at the OS level. A block, *might* consist of [Size][Returned Memory starts here][Size]. C sees only the middle bit, the OS sees only the outer bit. As far as the OS is concerned, only going beyond the end pieces is going "out of range".

Comment: Most C compilers historically don’t try to catch those bugs at runtime because those checks slow down the program slightly. If you’re working with built-in arrays, you always, always, always want to check that you’re in bounds yourself, *e.g.* with `assert(index < n);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn’t.  You’re allowed to calculate the *address* `array + n`, for the purpose of checking that another address is less than it.  Trying to access the element `array[n]` is **undefined behavior**, which means the program becomes meaningless and the compiler is allowed to do anything whatsoever.  Literally anything; one old version of GCC, if it saw a `#pragma` directive, started a roguelike game on the terminal.  (Thanks, Revolver_Ocelot, for reminding me: that was technically implementation-defined behavior, a different category.)  Even calculating the address `array + n + 1` is **undefined behavior**.

Because it can do anything, the particular compiler you tried that on decided to let you shoot yourself in the foot.  If, for example, the next two words after the array were the header of another block in the heap, you might get a memory-corruption bug.  Or maybe a compiler stored the array at the top of your memory space, the address `&array[n+1] is a`NULL` pointer, and trying to dereference it causes a segmentation fault.  Or maybe the next page of memory is not readable or writable and trying to access it crashes the program with a protection fault.  Or maybe the implementation bounds-checks your array accesses at runtime and crashes the program.  Maybe the runtime stuck a canary value after the array and checks later to see if it was overwritten.  Or maybe it happens, by accident, to work.

In practice, you really want the compiler to catch those bugs for you instead of trying to track down the bugs that buffer overruns cause later.  It would be better to use a `std::vector` than a dynamic array.  If you *must* use an array, you want to check that all your accesses are in-bounds yourself, because you cannot rely on the compiler to do that for you and skipping them is a major cause of bugs.

Comment: The behavior on encountering unknown pragma is _implementation-defined_, not _undefined_, so GCC example does not quite fit there.

Comment: That spoils the joke.  It’s not as funny to say, your program could start a global thermonuclear war.

Answer (score 2):

If you write or read beyond the end of an array or other object you create with new, your program's behaviour is no longer defined by the C++ standard.

Anything can happen and the compiler and program remain standard compliant.

The most likely thing to happen in this case is you are corrupting memory in the heap.  In a small program this "seems to work" as the section of the heap ypu use isn't being used by any other code, in a larger one you will crash or behave randomly elsewhere in a seemingoy unrelated bit of code.

But arbitrary things could happen.  The compiler could prove a branch leads to access beyond tue end of an array and dead-code eliminate paths that lead to it (UB that time travels), or it could hit a protected memory region and crash, or it could corrupt heap management data and cause a future new/delete to crash, or nasal demons, or whatever else.

Answer (score 1):

At the `for` loop you are assigning elements beyond the bounds of the loop and remember that C++ does not do bounds checking.

So when you initialize the array you are initializing beyond the bounds of the array (Say the user enters `3` for `length` you are initializing 1 to `array[0]` through `array[5]` because the condition is `n <= length + 1`;

The behavior of the array is unpredictable when you go beyond its bounds, but most likely your program will crash. In this case you are going 2 elements beyonds its bounds because you have used `=` in the condition and `length + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that the `new []` operator allocate more memory than requested.

What is happening is that your code is running past the end of the allocated array.   It therefore has undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour means that the C++ standard imposes no requirements on what happens.  Therefore, your implementation (compiler and standard library, in this case) will be equally correct if your program SEEMS to work properly (as it does in your case), produces a run time error, trashes your system drive, or anything else.

In practice, all that is happening is that your code is writing to memory, and later reading from that memory, past the end of the allocated memory block.   What happens depends on what is actually in that memory location.   In your case, whatever happens to be in that memory location is able to be modified (in the loop) or read (in order to print to `std::cout`).

Conclusion:  the explanation is not that `new[]` over-allocates.   It is that your code has undefined behaviour, so can seem to work anyway.